# Make symbols standard for number keys in OS X

Tags: macos

When programming in OS X, one of the great annoyances to me is that I can't find a decent way to "invert" the number keys so that !@#$%^&*() becomes the standard while the shifted version becomes 1234567890. Is there a keyboard layout out there that can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the name [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) works for all Mac hardware not only macbooks and you can remap your keyboard with it.

Edit:

The setting you are looking for is under "Change Num Key (1...0)".